# How to turn off an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, stream, event-handling, record, listen

Im making an audio transcripter script for my webpage and i want it to stop listening the user when it capture silence, i can capture the silence, but i cant delete or turn off the event 'stopped_speaking'. Is there a way to do it? if its not, how can i resolve my problem? thx.

here my code:

```
function bg_startRecording() {    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: false,
        audio: true
        }).then(async function(stream) {
            recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'audio',
                mimeType: 'audio/wav',
                recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
                disableLogs: false,
                numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
            });
            recorder.startRecording();
            var options = {};
            speechEvents = hark(stream, options);
            speechEvents.on('stopped_speaking', function() {
                speechEvents.off('stopped_speaking'); <----- throw an error
                bg_stopRecording() //function to stop recording and transcript
            });

        }) 
};
```

The error:

```
main.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: speechEvents.off is not a function
    at Object.stopped_speaking (main.js:49)
    at harker.emit (hark.js:16)
    at hark.js:109
```

Comment: `speechEvents.stop()` will stop the polling and events will not be emitted.